# UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, listview

I made listview that loads a lot of stuff from sd card and shows in Listview. Now I am trying to make custom listview adapter to make that listview look better, but i am getting this error everytime `02-22 20:54:21.411: E/AndroidRuntime(17273): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView`

Here is my java code :

```
 musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
           musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext(), count, null));

    public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
           private Context mContext;
           Context context; 
        int layoutResourceId;    
        ListView data[] = null;
           public MusicAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ListView data[]){
               super();
               mContext = context;

                this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                this.context = context;
                this.data = data;
           }

           public int getCount() {
                 return count;
           }

           public Object getItem(int position) {
                 return position;
           }

           public long getItemId(int position) {
                 return position;
           }


           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View row = convertView;
               ListViewHolder holder = null ;

                 String id = null;
               if(row == null)
            {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent);
             holder = new ListViewHolder();
                       music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                       musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                       id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                       music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                       musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                       id += musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                      row.setTag(holder);
                      holder.txtTitle.setText(id);
                      holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
                      holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                    holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                 } else {
                       holder = (ListViewHolder)row.getTag();
                 }
               holder.txtTitle.setText(id);
               holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
                 return row;

           }

        }
     static class ListViewHolder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;
            TextView txtTitle;
 }
}
```

main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/PhoneMusicList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Listview row

```
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

         <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inflate your view like this:

`row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent);`

instead, you should:

`row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);`

This will tell the `parent`, in this case the `ListView`, not to attach the child.